Notifying FragmentStateAdapter About UpdatedUi
I am using FragmentStateAdapter for viewpager2. My viewpager2 is in MainActivity. in the adapter i have 3 fragments named HomeFragment,ServerlistFragment and SettingsFragment. I am updating HomeFragment when wireguard is connected but the ui is not updated and notifyDataSetChanged() is not working
    class ViewPagerAdapter(fragmentActivity: FragmentActivity) :         FragmentStateAdapter(fragmentActivity) {

      override fun createFragment(position: Int): Fragment {
      return when (position) {
        0 -> HomeFragment()
        1 -> ServerListFragment()
        2 -> SettingsFragment()
        else -> HomeFragment() // Default case
    }
}

override fun onBindViewHolder(
    holder: FragmentViewHolder,
    position: Int,
    payloads: MutableList<Any>
) {
    Log.d("uichangemares","")
    super.onBindViewHolder(holder, position, payloads)
}

override fun getItemCount(): Int {
    return 3 // Number of fragments
}

}
this is my adapter. This is onCreate() of mainactivity
override fun  onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {

     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
      binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
      setContentView(binding.root)
     adapter = ViewPagerAdapter(this)

    binding.viewPager.adapter = adapter

   //i am updating connectedStateUi livdata based on the connection state of wireguard in   homefragment        
        serversViewModel.connectedStateUi.observe(this) {
      Log.d("uichangemain","")
       adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()

        }
   
            binding.viewPager.registerOnPageChangeCallback(object : OnPageChangeCallback() {
              override fun onPageSelected(position: Int) {
            super.onPageSelected(position)
            when (position) {
                0 -> {
                    binding.bottomNav.setSelectedItemId(R.id.homeFragment)

                    changeBottomBgHome()
                }

                1 -> {
                    binding.bottomNav.setSelectedItemId(R.id.serverListFragment)
                    changeBottomBgOther()
                }

                2 -> {
                    binding.bottomNav.setSelectedItemId(R.id.settingsFragment)
                    changeBottomBgOther()
                }
            }
        }
    })


}

I tried notifyDatasetChanged
